# What is the use of Application preference plugin by Tue Topholm / Sugee

Tags: cordova, config, phonegap-plugins, settings.bundle

I am creating a Phonegap application and also I am using some plugins. Recently I found Appliaction preference plugin by Tue Topholm / Sugee ([here](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iOS/ApplicationPreferences#using-the-plugin)). I checked that in detail. But I wonder how can I use that.

Now I am using Phonegap version 2.7.0, and it has no .plist file and instead of that is using a config.xml file. We are setting necessary key value pairs inside that only. So, will it support above plugin? And if yes how can i use that?

I am asking this here because someone might have used this. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try it yourself and check if it's working or not after adding the key/value to config.xml. If it doesn't work you have to update the plugin to phonegap 2.7.0

Here you have the [plugin upgrade guide](https://github.com/apache/cordova-ios/blob/master/guides/Cordova%20Plugin%20Upgrade%20Guide.md)